# How to select (text) inspect element chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

In the attached screenshot I want to select the text in CSS so I can give it a display:none
I cant figure out to select it. Even a js, or jQuery solution would be appropriate. 
ive tried #text as what devtools says it is.
ive tried p.woocommerce-shipping-contents::after
that doesn't seem to let me hide it.

How can I hide this element with css, js, or jquery?

[image: cant select text]

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS does not have a selector for just text.  If you are able to modify the HTML, you might want to wrap your text in a `<span>` tag, add a class to it and then select that..

Comment: Also, could you please add a [mcve] of the code so that it's easier/faster to troubleshoot?